# Use PHP to restart process on Linux machine?

Tags: php

i need to make a web page (Which will of course be secured) to restart a process on my Linux machine.

I'm not much of a PHP guy, but so far I've tried about what i know (which is very minimal)

```
<?php
$getpid = shell_exec('pidof processineedtokill');
shell_exec('kill -9 $getpid');
?>
```

See the thing is, I know 
"kill -9 $getpid" will not work. How would i use $getpid in a " (' ') "?

Thank you!

Comment: Interpolation only works in double quoted strings.

Comment: It may not work unless you either run your web server as the root user, or the process you're killing is running as the same user as the web server

Comment: @mario Thanks! I belive this is what i need! :).
I can set some permissions in sudoers to fix the issue for the webserver i believe!